# A finite group $G$ is called an $N$-group if the normalizer $N_G(P)$ of every non-identity p-subgroup $P$ of $G$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, simple-groups, solvable-groups

Prove that if $G$ is an $N$-group, then either (i) $G$ is solvable, or (ii) $G$ has a unique minimal normal subgroup $K$, the factor group $G/K$ is solvable, and $K$ is simple.

Suppose that $G$ is an $N$-group and $G$ is not solvable. Then we know that $G$ can not have a normal $P$ group. Also since for any non trivial normal subgroup $N$, let $P$ be a  sylow subgroup of $N$, then by the Fratini Argument $G = N_G(P)N$. So by the second isomorphism theorem $G/N = N_G(P)N/N \cong N_G(P)/N \cap N_G(P)$. So since $N_G(P)$ is solvable and quotients of solvable groups are solvable $N_G(P)/N \cap N_G(P)$ is solvable, and hence $G/N$ is solvable.

So it suffices to show that if $G$ is an $N$-group and $G$ is not solvable that $G$ has a minimal normal subgroup. Since $G$ is not solvable we know that if we keep taking the commutator subgroup of the previous commutator subgroup we eventually get for some integer $n$ that $G^{n} = G^{n+ 1} \neq 1$ where $G^n$ is the $n^{th}$ commutator subgroup. Now we have that $G^n$ is characteristic and hence normal.

So I am convinced that I want to let $K$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G^{n}$, since $

Comment: Let $K$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Is $K$ soluble first of all?

Comment: If we are assuming $G$ is not solvable then no, because since $G/K$ is solvable if $K$ were also solvable then $G$ would have to be.

Comment: So what is the structure of $K$ then?

Comment: The minimal normal subgroup of an N-group cannot be solvable because a product of a solvable normal subgroup and a solvable subgroup is solvable (Frattini trick). But why is it simple? It may be a direct power of a simple subgroup.

Comment: A group of even order that is greater than or equal to $60$? Since any characteristic subgroup of $K$ is normal in $G$ we have that $Z(K) = 1$ and $K' = K$.

Comment: Ah, apparently you don't know the result that a minimal normal subgroup is always the direct product of a number of isomorphic simple groups (abelian or non-abelian).

Comment: Wait, do you want this property to hold for all primes $p$, or a particular prime $p$? An N-group should be for all primes $p$, no?

Comment: For all primes $p$

Comment: Your best bet is to show that if $X$ is a non-abelian simple group then $X\times X$ is not a subgroup of $G$. This should give you the result.

Comment: (Once you have completed this step I will undelete the answer I have posted and then deleted, thus giving a complete proof.)

Comment: Wouldn't $X \times X$ have to be a subgroup since for any subgroups $H, K$ we have $HK$ is a subgroup iff $HK = KH$?

Comment: I mean that if $X\times X$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$ for $X$ non-abelian simple then $G$ is not an $N$-group.

Comment: I think you want me to prove that if $X \times X$ is a subgroup then $X$ is the normalizer of a $P$ group since a non abelian simple group can't be solvable, but I still think that for any group $G$ and subgroup $H$ that $H \times H$ is automatically a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Your claim that $H\times H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $H$ is cannot be correct. For one, let $H=G$. Then you want $G\times G$ to be a subgroup of $G$. For $G$ finite that's not going to work. But you have the right idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a full proof to complete the question.

Let $M$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Then $M$ is the direct product of isomorphic simple groups $S$. If $S$ is cyclic then $M$ is a $p$-subgroup such that $N_G(M)=G$, so $G$ is soluble. Thus $S$ is non-abelian and $M$ is the direct product of $n$ copies of $S$. If $Q$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S$ for some $p\mid |S|$ then $n-1$ copies of $S$ appear in $N_G(Q)$. Since $N_G(Q)$ is soluble though, this means $n=1$. Thus $M$ is non-abelian simple.

Finally, by a Frattini argument $G=M\cdot N_G(Q)$, where $Q\in\mathrm{Syl}_p(M)$. Since $N_G(Q)$ is soluble by assumption, and $G/M\cong N_G(Q)/N_M(Q)$, we see that $G/M$ is soluble.

Comment: Why do $n- 1$ copies of $S$ appear in $N_G(Q)$?

Comment: Because $Q\times S\times S\times \cdots \times S$ is a subgroup of $M\leq G$. So each of these copies of $S$ is contained in $C_G(Q)\leq N_G(Q)$.

Comment: This is Problem 2C.1 from Isaacs' FGT.

Answer (score 0):

The question is part b) of Problem 2C.1 from Isaacs' FGT.

Part a) establishes that if $G$ is an $N$-group and $1<N\triangleleft G$, then $\bar G=G/N$ is solvable. To see this pick a prime divisor $p$ of $|N|$ and apply the Frattini Argument to conclude that $G=N_G(P\cap N)N$, whenever $P\in\text{Syl}_p(N)$.

For part b) take $N$ to be minimal normal in $G$. Now observe that if $G$ isn't solvable, the $r$th derived groups $G^{(r)}$ are never trivial, unlike their quotients $\bar G^{(r)}$ which eventually are by part a). Conclude that $N=G^{(r)}$ for $r$ large enough.