# What does "proper" mean in this context?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, solvable-groups

Part a) of Problem 2C.1 of Isaacs' Finite Group Theory reads

*Show that every proper homomorphic image of an $N$-group is solvable.*

What does "proper" mean here? Please note that I'm not asking for a solution to the problem, just a clarification of its statement, so I can work myself on it. (Incidentally, the definition of *solvable* group comes later in the book in Chapter 3, a rare oversight in Isaacs.)

Comment: I don't have the book to hand, but this most likely means a homomorphic image which isn't isomorphic to the group itself.

Comment: A *proper* subset $N$ of $G$ is a subset $N$ which isn't the whole set $G$. A proper subgroup $N$ of $G$ is a subgroup with $N\neq G$. A *nontrivial* subgroup $N$ of $G$ is one with $N\neq 1$.

Comment: @elemelons These are only necessarily equivalent for finite groups, as there are infinite groups which surject onto themselves with non-trivial kernel. So the phrase "proper homomorphic image" is surprisingly subtle!

Comment: For a solution to the problem see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4727047/269050.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group $H$ is a *homomorphic image* of a group $G$ if there exists a surjective homomorphism $\phi:G\twoheadrightarrow H$. If $G$ is finite then $H$ is a *proper* homomorphic image if $G\not\cong H$; equivalently, if $\ker(\phi)$ is non-trivial.

As Isaac's book is about finite groups, this is the case here.

---

For infinite groups, these two conditions are not in general equivalent (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/79852/10513)) and so you should be careful using this term.